# How to optimally stop a find which pipes to a bash script

Tags: process-management

I'm using the following to convert a video library from x264 to x265.  But I can't stop it without doing a Ctrl-C on the bash script whilst it's working.

```
find /mnt/local/int001/media/TV/ \
\( -name '*[xXhH]264*.mkv' -o -name '*[xXhH].264*.mkv \) \
! -name '*[xX]265*' -type f -exec /usr/local/bin/ConvertTo265.sh {} +
```

But then the find process keeps spitting out results and the script re-triggers.  How can I implement this so I can stop it when required. I have several months of conversion ahead and need to be able to stop it for maintenance etc.

Comment: You are missing a single quote in `'*[xXhH].264*.mkv \) `

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't Ctrl+C stop it? What's missing?

Comment: As per the answer below, it only stops the bash script. Find continues to pipe more results, which results in the script being re triggered.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the Ctrl-C is only killing the active conversion sub process(es). You could try using Ctrl-Z to suspend it, then kill off the suspended process with `kill %1`.

Alternatively spin up another terminal and kill the `find` process from there.